# Why this program got terminated in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

There is nothing wrong with the code but when i compiles it, the header of console shows this

`<terminated> CopyFileToNewFile[Java Application]C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\javaw.exe`

```
package com.princess;
public class CopyFileToNewFile {

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        try(
            FileInputStream in =  new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("new.txt");

           ) {

            int c;
            while((c=in.read())!=-1)
            {
                out.write(c);
            }

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

I am using JAVA 1.7 version also i'm not used to with Eclipse

Comment: Does it quit prematurely ?

Comment: no,it doesn't it just shows that <terminated> message after i hit run

Comment: This ran perfectly fine. I'm running 1.7 using Netbeans. Terminated just means Eclipse finished running.

Comment: Does it write your file? The <terminated> message just means that it finished.

Comment: it is supposed to write on the new.txt but i got nothing after running it

Comment: @vinay, are you sure you want to be writing to the E:\ drive? Maybe you meant C:\ Drive.

Comment: yes i'm sure otherwise it throws me fileNotFoundException btw

Comment: I took your code verbatim (only replaced E:\ with C:\ ) and it copied over `myFile.txt` into `new.txt`. Not sure why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Perhaps having an explicit close statement?

Comment: @vinay, add `out.close();` after closing your `while` loop.

Comment: The program that terminated was CopyToNewFile, which is not the program CopyFileToNewFile that you have on your screen.

Comment: @robotlos pls see my edit in code now i copied the myfile.txt into directory of the project but still doesn't produce new.txt

Comment: @robotlos actually try block take care of closing the resource in java 1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<terminated>` in Eclipse simply means the program finished executing, not that something went wrong.

If you want to keep the program "alive", you have to make it wait for something, like user input, Thread.sleep(), or something else.

Comment: but it doesn't write to new.txt

Comment: Are you sure you're executing the right java file? In your question it says `<terminated> CopyToNewFile` but your class name is `CopyFileToNewFile`?

Comment: Does it create `new.txt` if you delete it? Are you sure there is anything to read in `myfile.txt`? Seems strange that it doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: if i delete the myfile.txt from the project directory... program is throwing file not found exception

Comment: Yes of course, but what if you delete `new.txt`? Does it get recreated? I just tried your code and it's working fine for me...

Comment: i haven't created new.txt as program is supposed to do it by itself. isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108337/discussion-between-badcash-and-vinay).